# Run a program from python several times whitout initialize different shells

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to run a compiled Fortran numerical model from Python. It is too complex to compile it using F2PY without implement several changes in the Fortran routines. This is why I am just calling its executable using the subprocess module.

The problem is that I have to call it few thousands of times, and I have the feeling that generating soo many shells is slowing the whole thing.

My implememtation (It is difficult to provide a reproducible example, sorry) looks like:

```
import os
import subprocess

foo_path = '/path/to/compiled/program/'
program_dir = os.path.join(foo_path, "FOO")            #FOO is the Fortran executable
instruction = program_dir + " < nlst"                  #It is necesary to provide FOO a text file (nlst)
                                                       #with the configuration to the program

subprocess.call(instruction, shell=True, cwd=foo_path) #run the executable
```

Running it in this way (inside a loop), it works well and FOO generates a text file output that I can read from python. But I'd like to do the same keeping the shell active and just providing to it the `"nlst"` file path. Another nice option may be start an empty shell and keep it waiting for  the `instruction` string, that will look like `"./FOO < nlst"`. But I am not sure about how to do it, any ideas?

Thanks!

[Edited] Something like this should work but `.comunicate` ends `process` and a second call does not work:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_path = '/path/to/FOO/'
process = Popen(['bash'], stdin=PIPE, cwd=foo_path)
process.communicate(b'./FOO < nlst')
```

Comment: You could use a pipe (see popen()) that allows your python script to send strings. On the other side of the pipe you run a shell script that does a `read` and starts your Python script with the argument it just read from stdin.

Comment: Maybe threading works for you - [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ronald . I think your approach is exactly what I want. But not sure about how to implement it. I'll edit the question with my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution using the `pexpect` module,

```
import pexpect
import os.path

foo_path = '/path/to/FOO/'
out_path = '/path/to/FOO/foo_out_file'  #path to output file
child = pexpect.spawn('bash', cwd=foo_path)
child.sendline('./FOO < nlst')

while not os.path.exists(out_path): #wait until out_path is created
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend my comment, here is an example for threading with your code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

foo_path = '/path/to/compiled/program/'
program_dir = os.path.join(foo_path, "FOO")            #FOO is the Fortran executable
instruction = program_dir + " < nlst"                  #It is necesary to provide FOO a text file (nlst)
                                                       #with the configuration to the program

def your_function():
    subprocess.call(instruction, shell=True, cwd=foo_path) #run the executable

# create executor object
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)  # uncertain of how many workers you might need/want

# specify how often you want to run the function
for i in range(10):
    # start your function as thread
    executor.submit(your_function)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this do not solve the problem as 'your_function' will create a new shell every time it is run in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

What I meant in my comment was something like the following Python script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_path = '/home/ronald/tmp'
process = Popen(['/home/ronald/tmp/shexecutor'], stdin=PIPE, cwd=foo_path)

process.stdin.write("ls\n")
process.stdin.write("echo hello\n")
process.stdin.write("quit\n")
```

And the shell script that executes the commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read cmdline; do
    if [ "$cmdline" == "quit" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    eval "$cmdline" >> x.output
done
```

Instead of doing an "eval", you can do virtually anything.
Note that this is just an outline of a real implementation.
You'd need to do some error handling. And if you are going to use this in a production environment, be sure to harden the code to the limit.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try to implement it without a shell script, but If I can't this is an option. Thanks!